# Enumerate function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, enumerate

Can someone explain this to me.

So, I have a list `s` with numbers from -1 to 1 and I want to extract position of certain numbers in a list.

Example:

```
s= [-1, 0.5, 0.2, -0.9]

z = enumerate(s)
y1 = []
for i,j in z:
    if j<=-0.8 and j>=-1:
        k = i
        y1.append(k)

y2 = []
for i,j in z:
    if j<=0.8 and j>=-0.8:
        k = i
        y2.append(k)
```

I get `y1 = [0, 3]` and `y2 = []`

But if I define second `enumerate`:

```
z1 = enumerate(s)
y1 = []
for i,j in z1:
    if j<=-0.8 and j>=-1:
        k = i
        y1.append(k)

z2 = enumerate(s)
y2 = []
for i,j in z2:
    if j<=0.8 and j>=-0.8:
        k = i
        y2.append(k)
```

I get result `y1 = [0, 3]` and `y2 = [1, 2]`

Why do I need second `enumerate`?

Comment: Maybe `enumerate` is lazy? Try `z = list(enumerate(s))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`enumerate` returns an iterator to the sequence. Once traversed, it cannot be used again:

```
In [1]: l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

In [2]: e = enumerate(l)

In [3]: e
Out[3]: <enumerate at 0x7fad7aea25e8>

In [4]: list(e)
Out[4]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

In [5]: list(e)
Out[5]: []
```

You could wrap it with a list:

```
In [6]: e = list(enumerate(l))

In [7]: e
Out[7]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

In [8]: list(e)
Out[8]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]

In [9]: list(e)
Out[9]: [(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5)]
```

You could also use list comprehensions in order to simplify your solution:

```
y1 = [i for i, x in enumerate(s) if -1 <= x <= -0.8]
y2 = [i for i, x in enumerate(s) if -0.8 <= x <= 0.8]
```

Comment: @VlS, you are welcome! Do not forget to accept one of the presented answers (green tick just below the post score) in order to help people facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

From python [docs](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/), the implementation of enumerate is as follow:

```
def enumerate(collection):
    'Generates an indexed series:  (0,coll[0]), (1,coll[1]) ...'     
    i = 0
    it = iter(collection)
    while 1:
        yield (i, it.next())
        i += 1
```

Since it uses 'yield', it is a generator which stores the state when you iterate through it once in line

```
for i,j in z
```

To use only one enumerate, convert the values of the generator to a list and reuse the list :

```
s= [-1, 0.5, 0.2, -0.9]

z = list(enumerate(s))

y1 = []

for i,j in z:
    if j<=-0.8 and j>=-1:
        k = i
        y1.append(k)

y2 = []
for i,j in z:
    if j<=0.8 and j>=-0.8:
        k = i
        y2.append(k)

print(y1)
print(y2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 3]
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

`enumerate` is a lazy generator, once called and traversed all the way it's done. So, I think it's better you include its call directly in the `for` loop:

```
s= [-1, 0.5, 0.2, -0.9]

y1 = []
for i,j in enumerate(s):
    if -1 <= j <= -0.8: 
        y1.append(i)

y2 = []
for i,j in enumerate(s):
    if -0.8 <= j <= 0.8:
        y2.append(i)
```

A side note:

`if j<=-0.8 and j>=-1:` can be replaced by `if -1 <= j <= -0.8:`